# video.js html5 video choppy in safari

Tags: safari, video.js

I've implemented video.js on one of our sites, and our videos play normally in every browser except for Safari on Mac.  It's choppy at best in Safari, if it continues to play at all.

Here's one example video, though all exhibit this behavior:

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/e9M4a/6/

```
<div class='videoWrapper'>
  <video
      class='video-js vjs-default-skin' 
      poster='https://goodtogo-production.s3.amazonaws.com/videos/posters/000/000/021/large/Group_Hospitality.png' 
      data-setup='{ "controls": true, "autoplay": false, "preload": "auto", "height": 320, "width": 568}'>
    <source src='https://goodtogo-production.s3.amazonaws.com/videos/files/000/000/021/original/Group_Hospitality_v1_with_tag.mp4' type='video/mp4'></source>
  </video>
</div>
```

I've googled a bit and found this link http://help.videojs.com/discussions/problems/504-no-audio-and-choppy-video-in-safarimac suggesting that it could be an encoding problem, but as far as I can tell the encoding is OK, and it plays normally via Quicktime.

The video playback is choppy for me in the jsfiddle via Safari as well, so I'm pretty sure it's not something in our particular implementation on the site.

Can anyone see what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply because your mp4 file is huge in terms of file size, it's over 140mb! It's very choppy in my browser too (IE10). For a video that's 4:17 long you should be able to encode it to within 10mb only.

Also the video dimensions are big as well. Resize the video to only the dimensions you're using in the player (width: 568 and height: 320).

Then watch your movie stream smoothly.

Comment: So, are you saying that if we want to watch a video that's over 140Mb (like a video of a soccer match, which can be over 1GB), we cannot use VideoJS in Safari on a Mac?

Comment: Nope it's down to the bitrate of the movie. If it was excessively high it would affect all players not just video.js. Imagine if the video was 1gb for 1 minute of video would be outrageous. But 1gb spread over say 360 minutes would be perfectly reasonable. The aim of the game is optimisation, a principal you would do in a normal web build such as ensuring your graphics are the smallest file size possible without losing too much quality.